# Screen goes off as soon I dial or receive a call. CyanogenMod 7.1- stable

Tags: cyanogenmod, calls, screen, motorola-defy

In stable mod 7.1, I am facing this problems. I don't know if its a bug or what, please help me out.

**My screen goes off as soon I dial or receive a call. After that I am unable to end the call as it never wakes up. Pressing the power button has no effect.**.

The problem is not just related to ending the calls. I am unable to do anything on my phone as it never wakes up. Then I have to either pull off the battery and restart the phone or plug in the charger to wake it up. It never happened on stock ROM so no hardware problem. I checked the solution for this problem and it was "It seems to be the screen protector is at fault. CM7.1 doesn't play nice with it. I just cut a hole where the proximity sensor is and it basically fixed it. " But IMHO if the proximity sensor does not work properly with cyanogenMod then why does the power button also stop responding.

But if they are related then can you guys please tell me with an image where the proximity sensor is located on a Defy? So that I may try the other solution (cutting the screen protector).

Comment: Have you looked at the settings?  I don't remember where specifically they are under the CM settings but there are a few options to tweak screen behavior during calls.

Comment: I have tried virtually everything out their in settings, but no luck...

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem. After rebooting for bout 5 times its working fine. And it has nothing to do with the settings.

Comment: rebooting five times means exactly what? That you just switched on the phone and did a reboot for five times.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and found out it was due to the proximity sensor being blocked.