# Screen goes dark and phone goes unresponsive whenever I make/receive a call

Tags: calls, samsung-galaxy-ace, system-freeze

I changed the SIM card on my Samsung Galaxy Ace to another one. Now, whenever I make/receive a call, the screen goes dark and the phone goes unresponsive.

Pressing buttons randomly eventually sets the phone free, but this takes a long time (a few minutes).

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy Ace running Android 2.3.4 and a stock ROM, and the CPU speed is limited using SetCPU: can this be the cause of the problem?

The problem on this question is similar: [Screen goes off as soon I dial or receive a call. CyanogenMod 7.1- stable](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14708/screen-goes-off-as-soon-i-dial-or-receive-a-call-cyanogenmod-7-1-stable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling the proximity sensor seems to have worked: after some testing, I got no freezes at all.