# Screen goes blank during or after the call and does not come back

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, calls, system-freeze

I have an Android 2.3.6 phone.

The problem is the screen goes blank and unresponsive during or after the call.
I can't make or receive any call once the screen goes blank.
In Android 2.3.6, there is no proximity control.

If I do a missed call to my number, then the screen comes back.

Comment: Related: [Screen goes dark and phone goes unresponsive whenever I make/receive a call](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22408/16575)

Answer (score 0):

The free app [Screebl Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keyes.screebl.lite&hl=en) will fix this problem with phone calls. However, it creates another annoying problem after installation - the screen won't shut off or standby without you physically tapping the phone's power button.

Tested on a Samsung Galaxy Proclaim, running Android 2.3.6 Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just hit the power button. Your call won't terminate. It may have been meant to be intuitive, to save juice.  I use Speaker a lot, and need to hit the power button to end a call.