# Display Shuts Off During Calls

Tags: calls, screen

Hate to post this - however, I searched all other posts related to this and have not found a solution or the exact same problem so here it goes.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy SII X

Android: 4.0.4

This is so bloody annoying. During any call whether on speaker or using the phone in the traditional manner, the screen shuts off after a minute or so, even though my display is set to shut off after 5 minutes of inactivity.

I have taken the following actions to no avail:

- my screen protector does not cover the proximity sensor;
- the proximity sensor is clean;
- I have disabled proximity sensor (phone>call settings>turn on proximity sensor);
- I have disabled automatic brightness (settings>display>brightness); and
- set the Bluetooth visible time-out setting to "never time-out" (settings>bluetooth>settings>visible time-out)

All of the above have been suggested within this and/or other forums. However, none of these solutions corrected this most annoying problem.

Some have suggested that the phone is the issue - however, I suspect that there may be a software issue and that a patch or fix may be available and would hate to have to exchange phones yet again.

Any and all suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Duplicate? [When making calls the screen turns off](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23481)

Comment: Read the post you referred me to and I had seen that before, hence my list of actions taken to date. However, I did miss mentioning that I also tried dialing *#36# as per several suggestions and received the following responses "USSD code running..." followed by "Connection problem or invalid MMI code" Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: \*#36#, is unique to the device in question, "*Karbonn A9, Android 2.3.6*" and thus not the right code for your handset, so no worry, you're not doing something incorrectly. Best to google for samsung shortcodes to see what's the right code for your device. :)